# Convex closure of the support of a Levy Process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, convex-analysis

Given a Levy Process $X_{t}$ on a filtered Probability Space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F}_{t},P)$ with distribution-function $F_{t}$ for $X_{t}$.
We look now for the cumulant transform $\phi_{1}$ of $X_{1}$
\begin{align}
\phi_{1}(s)=\log E\left[e^{s X_{1}}\right]
\end{align}
The domain of $\phi_{1}$ is the set of values $s$ for which the upper Expectation is finite, so
\begin{align}
dom \phi_{1}:=N =\{s : \int e^{sX_{1}}dP<\infty\}=\{s: \int e^{sx}dF_{1}<\infty\}
\end{align}
This set is convex.
We assume that $\phi_{1}$ is strictly convex on its domain N.
We assume that, $\phi_{1}$ is steep, that means: Given $s_{1} \in \partial N$  and $s_{0}\in N^{\circ}$ define $s_{p}:=(1-p)s_{0}+ps_{1}$
\begin{align}
\frac{d \phi_{1}(s_{p})}{dp}\rightarrow \infty \mbox{ for } p\uparrow 1\,.
\end{align}
Let K denote the closure of the convex hull of the support of the random variable $X_{1}$.

**It is now stated**: Und the steepness and strictly convex conditions, it holds, that 
K is equal to the closure of the convex hull of the support of $X_{t}/t$, for $t>0$.

Remark: the support of a measure $\nu$ is the minimal closed set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^{k}$, for which $\nu(S^{c})=0$.

**My idea, how to prove this:**
Actually i didnt get it from straight calculations but maybe i did miss something.

Therefore I follow the idea of Brown, Fundamentals of Statistical Exponential Families Theorem 3.6 page 74. My notation is adapted to his notation, so noone is confused.
This theorem just states: For our domain $N$ we define the natural exponential Families $\{P_{1,s}:s\in N\}$ of measures by
\begin{align}
\frac{dP_{1,s}}{dP}=e^{sX_{1}-1\cdot\phi_{1}(s)}.
\end{align}
The Theorem now states: Under our given assumptions the mapping 
\begin{align}
\epsilon: N^{\circ} &\rightarrow  K^{\circ} \\
s &\rightarrow \dot{\phi}_{1}(s)=E_{1,s}[X_{1}]
\end{align}
is an homeomorphism (continous, 1-1 , onto). Here $E_{1,s}[.]$ is the expectation with respect to the measure $P_{1,s}$.

So
\begin{align}
K^{\circ}=\dot{\phi}_{1}(N^{\circ})
\end{align}
So $K=cl \dot{\phi}_{1} (N^{\circ})$.

Let $\phi_{t}(s)$ denote the cumulant transfrom of $X_{t}$ with distribution function $F_{t}$ with domain 
\begin{align}
N_{t}:=\{s: \int e^{sX_{t}}dP<\infty\}=\{s:\int e^{sx}dF_{t}<\infty\}\,.
\end{align}
One can show, that $N_{t}=N$ and $\phi_{t}(s)=t\cdot \phi_{1}(s)$ due to the infinite divisible property of the Levy Prozess.
Define the exponential families $\{P_{t,s}:s \in N=N_{t}\}$
with 
\begin{align}
\frac{dP_{t,s}}{dP}=exp\left[sX_{t}-\underbrace{t\cdot \phi_{1}(s)}_{=\phi_{t}(s)}\right]
\end{align}
Then we apply the above stated theorem, so we get an homeomorphism from: $N^{\circ}_{t}\rightarrow $  $K^{\circ}_{t}$,

where $K_{t}$ is the closure of the convex hull of the support of $X_{t}$.
Summing all up we get:
\begin{align}
 K^{\circ}_{t}= \dot{\phi}_{t}(N^{\circ}_{t})=\dot{\phi}_{t}(N^{\circ})=t\dot{\phi}_{1}(N^{\circ})=t  K^{\circ}
\end{align}
Is this proven now?

If someone has easier results, i would be happy, if you could help me out.

**Since the stated Theorem is also based on convex properties, i've put this also in the convex-analysis area**